# Filter and sort an Observable array in Angular6

Tags: angular, sorting, filter, rxjs, observable

I have an observable array of POJO:

```
export interface SearchList {
id?: number;
createDttm?: string;
updateDttm?: string;
name?: string;
value?: number;
type?: string;
```

}

The array I get from backend is of sample below

```
[{"id":26,"createDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:40.773","updateDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:40.773","name":"APPROVALSTATUS1","value":1,"type":"APPROVAL_STATUS"},
 {"id":27,"createDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:40.846","updateDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:40.846","name":"APPROVALSTATUS2","value":2,"type":"APPROVAL_STATUS"},
 {"id":10,"createDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:39.48","updateDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:39.48","name":"STATUS1","value":42,"type":"STATUS"}, 
 {"id":21,"createDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:40.379","updateDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:40.379","name":"QUEUE1","value":3,"type":"QUEUE"}, 
 {"id":24,"createDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:40.624","updateDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:40.624","name":"QUEUE2","value":6,"type":"QUEUE"}, 
 {"id":23,"createDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:40.542","updateDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:40.542","name":"QUEUE3","value":5,"type":"QUEUE"}, 
 {"id":16,"createDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:39.965","updateDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:39.965","name":"STATUS2","value":60,"type":"STATUS"},
 {"id":7,"createDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:39.239","updateDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:39.239","name":"STATUS3","value":32,"type":"STATUS"}, 
 {"id":8,"createDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:39.318","updateDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:39.318","name":"STATUS4","value":40,"type":"STATUS"}, 
 {"id":15,"createDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:39.883","updateDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:39.883","name":"STATUS5","value":51,"type":"STATUS"},
 {"id":12,"createDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:39.642","updateDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:39.642","name":"STATUS6","value":44,"type":"STATUS"},
 {"id":18,"createDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:40.142","updateDttm":"2018-07-26T16:40:40.142","name":"STATUS7","value":100,"type":"STATUS"}]
```

In my parent component, I am sending an ngrx dispatch action to get the above data. I get the above data.

I want to then filter them by type 'STATUS', 'APPROVAL_STATUS' and 'QUEUE' as you can see from the array.

I want to also sort them by name in ascending order( alphabetical ) and then send them to the child component ( dumb component )

```
 //dispatching action here
 const SearchLists = 
this.store.select(fromStore.getSearchListData);


  //SearchLists has the array. Have to filter and sort here
 statusList: Observable<SearchList[]>; //this will contain objects filtered by type=='STATUS'

 queueList: Observable<SearchList[]>; //this will contain objects filtered by type=='QUEUE' 

 approvalStatusList:Observable<SearchList[]>; //this will contain objects filtered by type=='APPROVSAL_STATUS'

 this.statusList = SearchLists.pipe(map(lists => 
 lists.filter(list =>list.type =='STATUS')));

 this.queueList= SearchLists.pipe(map(lists => 
 lists.filter(list =>list.type =='QUEUE')));

 this.approvalStatusList= SearchLists.pipe(map(lists => 
 lists.filter(list =>list.type =='APPROVAL_STATUS')));


  //How to sort by alphabetical after filtering and send it to child component on load so I can bind to listbox
```

My question is about combination of filtering and sorting on an observable stream which is done via RXJS operators and hence the question marked as duplicate wouldnt apply to mine since that is plain js.

Comment: *I want to also sort them by ascending order( alphabetical )* `-` By what, type, name?

Comment: I want to sort by name

Comment: If I were you I would change the question and ask just "send it to child component on load" part. As after the filtering you can still sort in the way recommended to you; rxjs is still js. I guess your problem is related to events in rxjs; how to and when to use them.